# Can't Update package in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, server, package-management, 18.04, php

I use these command to install PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu Server 18.04

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6
```

and apt-get update not working after install PHP5.6

Error:

```
Err:8 packages.sury.org/php bionic Release 404 Not Found [IP: 2001:1488:ac15:ff90::150 443] Reading package lists... Done

E: The repository 'packages.sury.org/php bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Open "Software & Updates" and look for the "Other Software" tab. Uncheck the "packages.sury.org/php" url and try to "apt update" again.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot to say that I am using Ubuntu server :(